# Method contentScaleFactor (pixels per point) on a iPodTouch 5th generation

Tags: objective-c, ios7, view, ipod-touch

I just wrote this code:

```
NSLog(@" Constant scale factor %f",self.view.contentScaleFactor);
```

In my iPod touch 5th generation (retina display), the result is:

```
constant scale factor **1.000000**
```

Why is that? 1 pixel per point? Just confused, I expected to obtain 2 pixels per point !
Anyone?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479001/uiviews-contentscalefactor-depends-on-implementing-drawrect ?

Comment: Hi Martin, I saw the link you wrote but it does not answer (I think) in a clear way why the result is 1 instead of 2.